Transforming $\forall x \, P(x) \rightarrow \exists y \, Q(y)$
Is the equivalence $$p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \vee q $$ applicable when my conditional statement contains quantification? For example:
$$\forall x \, P(x) \rightarrow \exists y \, Q(y)\\
\equiv\neg (\forall x \, P(x)) \vee \exists y \, Q(y) \\
\equiv\exists x \, \neg P(x) \vee \exists y \, Q(y). $$
And can we transform quantified sentences to conjunction normal form without first converting them to prenex form ?

Quantified predicates are propositions (that’s why we quantify them, in some sense)


Is the equivalence $$p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \vee q $$ applicable when my conditional statement contains quantification?

Yes. In fact, it is applicable to any logic formula.
For example, you can apply the equivalence to $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$ to obtain $\forall x (\neg P(x) \lor Q(x))$, even though $P(x) \to Q(x)$ and $\neg P(x) \lor Q(x)$ are mere formulas, not sentences.

And can we transform quantified sentences to conjunction normal form without first converting them to prenex form ?

Hmmm, it seems that you are thinking that something like $\exists x \, \neg P(x) \vee \exists y \, Q(y)$ is in conjunctive normal form ... after all, it is of the form $p \lor q$, which is in conjunctive normal form.
But no, it is not in conjunctive (or disjunctive) normal form. A sentence is in conjunctive normal form if and only if it is a generalized conjunction of generalized disjunctions of literals, where a literal is an atomic sentences or the negation thereof. $\exists x \, \neg P(x) \vee \exists y \, Q(y)$ is a generalized conjunction of (a single) generalized disjunction of ... a couple of quantified sentences ... which are not literals.
Now, I suppose you could come up with some kind of notion of 'conjunctive quantified normal form' that would capture something like $\exists x \, \neg P(x) \vee \exists y \, Q(y)$, but what would be the point of that? Conjunctive and disjunctive normal forms are handy  notions exactly because you get literals at the end. That allows for interesting and useful algorithms to be applied to them to figure out questions about logical consequence, consistency, etc. I do not see any practical use for some notion of a 'conjunctive quantified normal form'
There is, however, a use for a 'quantified conjunctive normal form', which is a statement that is in prenex form (i.e. all quantifiers are at the front of the statement), and whose body is a formula in conjunctive normal form (and where we replace 'atomic sentence' with 'atomic formula'). Again, those kinds of statements are great to use for automated theorem provers.
But nore, this now requires two things.  First you need to get a statement in prenex form, and then you need to put the body in conjunctive normal form .. where obviously any equivalences as you indicated at the start of your post are going to be applied to formulas with free variables, rather than sentences.
